# forbid emacs to open org-mode menu in new frame

Tags: emacs, org-mode

My emacs's org-mode displays menu in the new frame(for instance TODO menu with options that raises  after pressing C-c C-t). The same thing with opening pdf files (it opens them in new frame as well).

How can I tell emacs to open them in the same frame as a new buffer ?

Comment: `C-c C-t runs the command org-todo`, what menu does that open ? How do you open pdf files, `C-c C-o` on links, I guess ? Are these all you'd like to open in the same frame ?

Answer (score 3):

For opening files, you can customize the `org-link-frame-setup` variable. It's help (<kbd>C-h v</kbd>) goes :

> **org-link-frame-setup** is a variable defined in `org.el'.
>
> Setup the frame configuration for following links.
>   When following a link with Emacs, it may often be useful to display
>   this link in another window or frame.  This variable can be used to
>   set this up for the different types of links.
>
> For FILE, use any of
>       **`find-file`**
>       `find-file-other-window`
>       `find-file-other-frame`

So the following in your `.emacs` file should do (it keeps the default values for everything else, but anyone knowledgeable at elisp is welcome to improve this code) :

```lisp
(setq org-link-frame-setup (quote ((vm . vm-visit-folder-other-frame)
               (vm-imap . vm-visit-imap-folder-other-frame)
               (gnus . org-gnus-no-new-news)
               (file . find-file)
               (wl . wl-other-frame)))
  )
```